# ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns

Tags: python

```
def calc_sigma_tau_FT(t):
    return_t = FT_df['Close'].pct_change(t)*100 
    return_t_mean = return_t.mean() 
    return_t_Mu_t_square = (return_t - return_t_mean)**2 
    sigma_tau = return_t_Mu_t_square.mean()**0.5 
    return sigma_tau
sigma_tau_FT = [[t,calc_sigma_tau_FT(t)] for t in range(1,10000)]
FT_sigma_tau_df = pd.DataFrame(sigma_tau_FT,columns=['sigma_tau'])
```

ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. It is not enough to show code and an error message. We need to understand *what is supposed to happen* when you run the code, what you have tried to understand the problem, and specifically *what you need to know*. You should also [try to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by reading the documentation or by [your own analysis](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example, does `sigma_tau_FT` get the value you expect?

Comment: Think carefully about how you create the data: `[[t,calc_sigma_tau_FT(t)] for t in range(1,10000)]`. The `[t, calc_sigma_tau_FT(t)]` part - that should give you one row of the data, yes? How many columns will it have? Why? When you create the Dataframe, it says `pd.DataFrame(sigma_tau_FT,columns=['sigma_tau'])`. The `columns=['sigma_tau']` - how many columns does that say the Dataframe will have? Do you see how that should cause a problem? Do you see how that relates to the error message?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you really have in variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.